# Downloading a huge amount of files from google driver

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

I have a client that send me an excel of all his employees with CVs links from google driver,
So I have to download the cv and upload it to our S3 servers, but after maybe 50 files google start returning 403 I have to wait a bit of time then download again.

Is there any way to download all files faster?

Thanks

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: There is no code, the code is a for loop on an array google drive links which I try to download 
The issue is with google limitation

Comment: You should always include your code and the full error message not just the error code.  Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 ([maybe this one](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_user_rate_limit_exceeded)) you are hitting is probably a rate limiting error.  These errors are used by google as flood protection.  The google drive api is a free api, which means you need to share it with other developers.

Is this really a time critical service?

There really is no way to speed it up, even if you put up multiple services google is going to put on the breaks by detecting your ip address or the user your authenticated with.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I can't download after a specific count.
This will take time no other solution